# Null parameter on web api post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a very simple web api controller:

```
public class CarrinhoController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string Adiciona([FromBody] string conteudo)
        {
            return "<status>sucesso</status";
        }
    }
```

Now I'm running the server and trying to test this method via `curl` like this:

```
curl --data "teste" http://localhost:52603/api/carrinho
```

The request is arriving in my controller. However, the parameter `conteudo` always comes empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `curl --data "conteudo=teste" http://localhost:52603/api/carrinho`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These posts explain similar problem in detail http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

On asp.net site http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).
>
> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body.

Add "Content-Type: application/json" on Fiddler will work.

[image]

Comment: This link is useful http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api. "Content-Type: application/json" is required.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to solve the problem (:

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the `Content-Type` you're sending determines how ASP.NET WebAPI binds parameters.

Try sending the following instead (form encoded)

```
conteudo=teste
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the binding to happen, you remove all parameters and read the posted data

```
var myContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Did that, but still comes empty :/

Comment: Can you try specifying the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header in your `curl` call?  Try my 2nd example if that does not work for you.

Comment: Tried specifying the content type and still comes null. Wierd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the parameter in the POST data to match the method parameter name. Change your `curl` data parameter to be this format:

```
parameter=value
```

For example:

```
curl --data "conteudo=teste" http://localhost:52603/api/carrinho
```

Comment: Did that, but still comes empty :/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how curl works to be honest, have you tried using tools like postman or Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

You might have an incorrect (malformed) request. WebAPI uses JSON serializer that ignores malformed request errors and just passes null through.

As an example,

- Incoming json:
  -

```js
{
    "MyProp":"<ASN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>"
}
```

```js
public class MyRequest
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action:

```js
[HttpPost]
[Route("inbound")]
[ResponseType(typeof(InboundDocument))]
public IHttpActionResult DoPost([FromBody]MyRequest myRequest)
{
  if (myRequest == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myRequest));//this line throws!
  ...
}
```