# usage of [From Body] in WebApi POST method gets NULL param

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, frombodyattribute

I am using [FromBody] in WebApi. And when I send requests to the POST method, the request doesnot have the passed body param.I receive a NULL in the param and also if I inspect the Request oibject it doesnt have the param in the Content. Tried using both fiddler and through a WebRequest. It worked when I removed the [FromBody] tag,I cpuld read it using the Request object. Any explanations to it?

Comment: You may take a look on this resolved question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878097/null-parameter-on-web-api-post-method

Comment: If you showed the posted data, the controller's action and perhaps some more information it would be possible to help you. Doing it without that info is impossible.